# how can i used the output of the instentiated module in verilog?

Tags: verilog

This is LSFR of 10 bits. I instentiated LSFR module in verilog.  you can see in the given code below .  the output of LSFR is Current State. i want to access each of its individual bits. but here i am getting 0 for Current_State. it is not updating.  please any one can help me ..

```
module LSFR_counter  #(parameter n=6)( output Reg, input clk, input reset);
        //parameter n=10; // Change more than n to change LFSR length.
        reg [n:1]Reg; //All procedure outputs must be registered
        reg [n:1] counter ;

        initial 
        counter =0 ;

        always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
            if
            (reset) Reg <=1;
            else
            begin
            counter <= counter+1 ;
            Reg <= {Reg[n-1:2], Reg[n]^Reg[1], Reg[n]};
            end
        endmodule 


 module Main( output Reg  input Clock , input reset 
       );
 reg   Fgf8,Emx2,Pax6,Coup_tfi,Sp8;        // Genes 
 reg   F,E,P,C,S;                          // Proteins

     reg [10:1] Current_State ;
   LSFR_counter  #(.n(10))   lsfr ( .Reg (Current_State), .clk (Clock ), .reset(reset) )  ;

     Fgf8     <= Current_State[N-0]  ;   // Gene
     F        <= Current_State[N-1]  ;   //  Protein 
     Emx2     <= Current_State[N-2]  ;
     E        <= Current_State[N-3]  ;
     Pax6     <= Current_State[N-4]  ;
     P        <= Current_State[N-5]  ;
     Coup_tfi <= Current_State[N-6]  ;
     C        <= Current_State[N-7]  ;
     Sp8      <= Current_State[N-8]  ;
     S        <= Current_State[N-9]  ;
    endmodule ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output of instentiation module in verilog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302364/output-of-instentiation-module-in-verilog)

Comment: i cannt understand ... what is duplicate for output that i used??

Comment: @Qui means, that this question is duplicating your previous question. Probably you should delete that one.

Comment: @Misal313: you've created second question regarding the same problem. You should rather edited previous one than created a new one.

Comment: @Eugene Sh , you said me that again type the question asp previous question was not in detail

Comment: @Misal313 Yes, but you have the ability to update your own question with new information or delete it.

Comment: @ Eugene SH . please edit this question that you feel error..  please for me.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems in the code presented:

1. The `Main` module has an output named `Reg`, which is not assigned any signal. So if you are expecting to get any value out of it, you won't.
2. The signals `Fgf8, F..`  and friends are assigned, but not used. **Update:** Actully the assignment is incorrect. If they are supposed to be assigned synchronously (on clock cycles), it should be wrapped in `always` block. If you mean to have a combinatorial circuit instead, you should use the `assign` statement.
3. The variable/signal `N` is not defined. Verilog is case-sensitive, so `n` != `N`.
4. in the `LSFR_counter`  module, the `counter` is not reset to initial value.

These are problems that can be seen so far.

Comment: Actually, signals `Fgf8, F...` are not assigned. To describe combinational circuits `assign` should be used.

Comment: Well, yeah. I guess it should be wrapped in an `always` block, if supposed to update synchronously.

Comment: @Misal313 Clock = synchronously. Therefore you need a ` always @(posedge Clock)` thing

Comment: i can not understand what are you saying   .. @Eugene SH

Comment: If some signals are updating on the **same clock**, they are said to be updated **synchronously**. If they are updated regardless of clock, they are said to be updated **asynchronously**.

Answer (score 0):

**In LSFR_counter:** you are mixing ANSI and non-ANSI header styles. This is illegal syntax. Maybe your simulator/synthesizer is allowing it, but it is not supported and a bad practice.

You should use ANSI: [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 23.2.2.2 *ANSI style list of port declarations*

```
module LSFR_counter  #(parameter n=6)( output reg [n:1] Reg, input clk, input reset);
  reg [n:1] counter;
  // ...
```

or non-ANSI: [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 23.2.2.1 *Non-ANSI style port declarations*

```
module LSFR_counter  #(parameter n=6)( Reg, clk, reset);
  output Reg;
  input clk;
  input reset;
  reg [n:1] Reg;
  reg [n:1] counter;
  // ...
```

Non-ANSI is for IEEE Std 1364-1995 and backward comparability with In later versions of IEEE 1364 and all versions of IEEE 1800. Support for ANSI existed since IEEE Std 1364-2001.

---

**In Main:** Nothing is driving `Reg`. The other signals (eg: `Fgf8`, `F`, `Emx2`, etc.) are never declared and have illegal assignment. `N` is also never defined. I'll assume it is a parameter. You may declare them as reg and assign in a combinational block:

```
parameter N=10;
reg Fgf8,F, ... ,Sp8,S;
always @* begin
  Fgf8     = Current_State[N-0]  ;   // Gene
  F        = Current_State[N-1]  ;   //  Protein 
  // ...
  Sp8      = Current_State[N-8]  ;
  S        = Current_State[N-9]  ;
end
```

Or declare as wires and assign with continuous assignment:

```
parameter N=10;
wire Fgf8     = Current_State[N-0]  ;   // Gene
wire F        = Current_State[N-1]  ;   //  Protein 
// ...
wire Sp8      = Current_State[N-8]  ;
wire S        = Current_State[N-9]  ;
```

Both with synthesize the same.